# Get the date from a column in database SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table column called as `VoyageDate` and it has values like this: `Nov 25, 2021 12:00:00.0 AM`. I try to view these dates in the frontend  in this format `YYYY-MM--DD`. To do this I tried like this:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS "VoyageDate") AS "voyageDate"
```

But it does not work correctly. How can I do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select should be written like this

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), "YYYY--MM--DD") as "voyageDate";
```

You need to use function format(), to see the date in expected format.

You can read more here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_format.asp

If you are trying to read the value from column in table XXX (you don't specify it in question so replace the XXX with name of table) then the Select should look like this

```
SELECT FORMAT(VoyageDate, "YYYY--MM--DD") as "voyageDate" from XXX;
```